# Runnable in java spend more time to complete

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a native `java android` application, i'm trying to monitorize data usage using a [Handler](http://%20developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

And a thread:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
```

Why if i monitor data usage it always spend 10 more milliseconds than expected?

**1000 milliseconds**

```
02-23 04:29:00.829: D/DATA USAGE(1387): RECEIVED[0.454] Mb - SENT[0.154] Mb
02-23 04:29:01.839: D/DATA USAGE(1387): RECEIVED[0.472] Mb - SENT[0.155] Mb
02-23 04:29:02.849: D/DATA USAGE(1387): RECEIVED[0.473] Mb - SENT[0.157] Mb
02-23 04:29:03.859: D/DATA USAGE(1387): RECEIVED[0.477] Mb - SENT[0.160] Mb
```

**5000 milliseconds:**

```
02-23 04:17:17.669: D/DATA USAGE(1387): RECEIVED[0.193] Mb - SENT[0.065] Mb
02-23 04:17:22.679: D/DATA USAGE(1387): RECEIVED[0.194] Mb - SENT[0.065] Mb
02-23 04:17:27.689: D/DATA USAGE(1387): RECEIVED[0.194] Mb - SENT[0.065] Mb
02-23 04:17:32.699: D/DATA USAGE(1387): RECEIVED[0.194] Mb - SENT[0.065] Mb
02-23 04:17:37.709: D/DATA USAGE(1387): RECEIVED[0.194] Mb - SENT[0.065] Mb
```

Comment: @isnot2bad is an `Android` object http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: i edited my question, sorry, I totally forgot...